# How to open a port in Centos 6

Tags: centos, port, centos6

I'm a newbie at Centos. I need to open a few ports in Centos.

I've googled it a little bit, and found  something like this.

```
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 143 -j ACCEPT
```

But it gives the following error when i try to restart iptables

```
iptables: Applying firewall rules: iptables-restore: line 13 failed
```

How can I open ports in Centos 6

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to open a single port:

```
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 143 -j ACCEPT
```

For multiple, you can use the following instead (or repeat the above line multiple times):

```
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp -m multiport --dports 22,80,143 -j ACCEPT
```

The reason your line doesn't work is likely because you don't have a chain named 'RH-Firewall-1-INPUT'. CentOS 6 simply uses 'INPUT' as the chain name. You'll note something like the following at the top of the default config, naming the chains that exist:

```
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
```

Just to explain a bit further, the line `-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 143 -j ACCEPT` means:

- `-A`: append a rule
- `INPUT`: to the INPUT chain
- `-m state`: use the 'state' module
- `--state NEW`: only look for NEW connections (i.e. not those that are previously established/related)
- `-m tcp`: use the tcp module
- `-p tcp`: look for packets using the TCP protocol
- `--dport 143`: look for packets with a destination port of 143

Comment: thanks for the explanations. I've added the rule and iptables restarted without any errors. But, still when I check the ports from an outside source,, they seem to be closed. Should I do something else to open the ports.

Comment: Two possibilities come to mind: a) order matters for iptables rules - if you have this rule after a rule to drop the packets for the chain (e.g. after `-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited`) then it will never come into play b) A lot of port scans will look for some service actually listening on the external interface on the desired port - so, if you haven't got an IMAP service (e.g. Dovecot) running, then the port may appear closed.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it by adding :

```
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```

right after the 22 port

```
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```

restart iptables and it should work, at least for me it worked.